# select without using distinct keyword

Tags: sql, oracle

I just want to select the ip address if at least 5 different customers have been used same ip for last 7 days. But result is wrong.

```
table_1
customer ip        date
1        0.0.0.0  15.11.2019
2        0.0.0.0  11.11.2019
3        0.0.0.0  09.11.2019
4        0.0.0.0  10.11.2019

table_2
customer ip       date
1        0.0.0.0  15.11.2019
6        1.2.2.2  11.11.2019
4        0.0.0.0  09.11.2019
8        0.0.0.0  10.11.2019
9        5.5.5.5  12.11.2019
```

The result should be 0.0.0.0 because customer 1,2,3,4 and 8 uses same ip for last 7 day.

```
SELECT y.ip,x.customer 
         from table_1 x
         inner join 
         table_2 y
         on y.ip = x.ip
         WHERE x.DATE > SYSDATE - 7
         group by y.ip,y.customer
         Having Count(y.customer)>=5
```

Comment: What do you mean "used the same ip"?  A non-working query doesn't do much to explain.  Sample data and desired results would be much more helpful.

Comment: You should not be grouping by customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your sample data, it looks like your data is spread over the two tables that have the same structure. If so, you want to `union all` both tables (instead of joining them), and then aggregate:

```
select t.ip
from (
    select t1.customer, t1.ip, t1.date from table_1 t1
    union all 
    select t2.customer, t2.ip, t2.date from table_2 t2
) t
where t.date > sysdate - 7
group by t.ip
having count(distinct t.customer) >= 5
```

Answer (score 2):

try like below using distinct count

```
SELECT y.ip
         from table_1 x
         inner join 
         table_2 y
         on y.ip = x.ip
         WHERE x.DATE > SYSDATE - 7
         group by y.ip
         Having Count(distinct y.customer)>=5
```